# The total derivative of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, $a \in U$ and the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable in $a$.

a) Show that for some $u,v \in \mathbb{R}$

$Df(a)= \begin{pmatrix} u & -v \\
v & u
\end{pmatrix}$

b) Show that $|f'(a)|=\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$.
c) Show that $Df(a)$ is the product of a scalar multiplication and a rotation.

Question a I could sort of answer using the Cauchy-Riemann equations. But then you would need that $f(a)$ can be written as $f(a)=f_1(a) + i f_2(a)$ which I'm not sure of. Furthermore by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations I get the "normal" derivative instead of the total. How can I obtain the total derivative and what is the total derivative of a complex function?

For question b I don't understand what $|f'(a)|$ is, because the total derivative would be a matrix but you need the normal derivative.

For question c I have no clue what I should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just do one possible way to solve part c here.  A rotation matrix $Q$ satisfies $QQ^{T} =I$ and det$(Q)=1$.  For example, a matrix  $\begin{pmatrix} cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$

Let $c$ be the unknown scalar. Suppose $u \not= 0$ (in this case it's obvious anyways).  If we take $\frac{u}{c} = cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{v}{c} = sin(\theta)$, then solving we get $\frac{v}{u} = tan(\theta)$.  So, factoring out, we have 
$Df(a)= \begin{pmatrix} u & -v \\
v & u
\end{pmatrix} = c\begin{pmatrix} \frac{u}{c} & -\frac{v}{c} \\
\frac{v}{c} & \frac{u}{c}
\end{pmatrix}= c\begin{pmatrix} cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$, where $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{v}{u})$